# Does Surface film in surface tension contain any water molecules?

Tags: forces

This might be a dumb question , but I have been taught that the surface film doesn't have any water molecules because they go down due to the net downward intermolecular force and hence the film doesn't contain molecules of water. if this is true then what does the surface film have or contain , please help me out with a detailed answer I'm  confused at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a liquid with its vapor in equilibrium above it. As we move from the liquid to the vapor, where exactly is position for the plane that defines the liquid surface? Is it marked by a perfectly abrupt change in molecular density? Or is it somewhere in a continuous change in density over a small but not infinitely small length scale?

Ultimately, the fundamental question above is not dumb. It has indeed been the source of significantly important conjectures and explorations about the structure and thermodynamics at liquid-vapor surfaces. References with descriptions from the basics to the deeply theoretical include Physical Chemistry of Surfaces (Adamson), An Introduction to Interfaces & Colloids (Berg), or Liquid Surfaces and Interfaces: Synchrotron X-ray Methods (Pershan and Schlossman). Chapters 1.2.1 and 1.2.2 of the latter especially each give a brief synopsis on surface layering and in-plane surface order for liquids, respectively.

When you review the range of descriptions that exist about the structure at surfaces, you can eventually conclude that confusion, disagreements, and ambiguities still remain. Some pictures for example suggest that atoms or molecules at the surface are denser in the lateral plane than in the bulk liquid, meaning the surface plane will have more atoms or molecules per unit area than a slice in the bulk liquid. Yet other references discuss the density fluctuations going perpendicular to the liquid-vapor surface as the more significant factor.

My summary view for a pure system is below. In this summary, I consider the simplest case where the atom or molecular particles are spheres with fluctuating dipole bonds only, i.e. only London dispersion forces. I also consider a liquid surface that is not subject to significant influences of such forces as gravity forces (capillarity) or other macroscopic fluctuations.

The liquid particles move around each other dynamically. Even on the surface, the particles move both laterally (in the surface plane) and vertically (perpendicular to the surface plane). The structure at the surface any point in time is in equilibrium within itself and with the planes above (vapor) and below (liquid) it.

As we move (upward) from the liquid to the vapor, we expect to transition from a region where any particle is completely surrounded by other particles at close packed, liquid-liquid distances to a region where the particles are not touching each other (the gas phase). In one picture, the transition happens through one plane, the surface plane. The particles immediately at the surface plane have no close-neighbor, London-dispersion bonding interactions occurring from the vapor side. The surface plane is therefore pulled closer *on average* to the liquid layer below it. This effect is called surface relaxation.

What happens to the area number density of particles in the lateral plane of the surface plane itself? Do the particles pack more closely, thereby giving rise to observations from surface tension, e.g. where insects cannot fall through into the liquid below?

I contend that pictures where liquid particles are packed laterally closer together on the immediate liquid surface plane with respect to their lateral packing density in the bulk liquid are mistaken. We should instead construct pictures where only the top plane relaxes inward toward the liquid plane below. A natural result in three dimensions is that the effective three-dimensional density immediately at the surface appears to be higher. Search for pictures of structure at liquid surfaces to see how density oscillations in the packing of liquid particles are even shown to propagate to a few layers below the surface.

In summary ...

The surface of a liquid to its vapor can be pictured as a plane of the atoms or molecules. Compared with the liquid phase packing density, atoms or molecules in a liquid surface plane should not necessarily be reported to be any further apart or closer together within the lateral directions on the surface plane. The surface plane of those atoms or molecules is however *on average* closer to the next-closest liquid plane; the surface plane is said to be relaxed inward to the liquid.

Comment: A citation or two connecting this description to the studies you mention would be helpful.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I have pointed to two textbooks (others certainly exist) and a far denser theoretical book. I know of no one reference source that otherwise does a carefully crafted analysis on what drives the structure at liquid surfaces from first principles.

Comment: Thank you sir !